# Alias an async function with await in ES6

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, alias

Suppose that I implemented function `fA` as a *synchronous* call, while in another module, such functionality is implemented using a different name (say `fB`) and as an *asynchronous* call.

To use the new module, I don't want to change every single existing calling of my function `fA` if possible. So,

Is there any way for me to give such asynchronous function call `fB` an alias as `fA`? Something like, e.g.:

`const fA = await fB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it that way.  `await` only works on a promise that your function returns, not on a function by itself.

And, there's no way to turn an asynchronous interface into a synchronous one - it just can't be done in Javascript.  So, if all your code that was using synchronous `fA()` wants to now use asynchronous `fB()` that returns a promise, you're going to have to change everywhere you are now calling `fA()` to use the promise that `fB()` returns wither with `await` or `.then()`.  No way around that.

Of course, if you showed us the actual code for `fA()` and for `fB()` and the code that's using `fA()`, we might have more specific ideas on how best to adapt the existing code that calls `fA()`.

Right now your question is a theoretical question so all we can offer is a theoretical answer.  Stackoverflow answers can often be more helpful with real code so we can offer specific suggestions that fit into your actual code.

---

Note, you might be tempted to try to make a wrapper for `fB()` like this:

```
function fA() {
    return await fB();
}
```

But, you can't do that because in order to use `await`, you have to make it `async`:

```
async function fA() {
    return await fB();
}
```

Which is really just the same as:

```
function fA() {
    return fB();
}
```

Which means that the `fA()` wrapper still just returns a promise just like `fB()` did (all `async` functions return a promise), thus this wrapper doesn't accomplish anything for your caller.

---

To use an asynchronous function, the caller has to use whatever asynchronous calling mechanism the function uses (callback, promise, event, etc...).  So switching from a synchronous function that directly returns a value to an asynchronous function that communicates the result back via a promise requires changing the calling code.  There is no way around that.